# Conditionally Add Attribute

Tags: aurelia

Is it possible to conditionally add an attribute to an element using binding syntax? I am aware of `if.bind`, but that targets elements. Rather I am interested in targeting a specific attribute on an element.

Example:

```
<a href.bind="model.link">${model.text}</a>
```

If `model.link` is falsy, then I don't want the `href` at all--just treat the `<a />` as a container element.

I realize I could create two `<a />` tags--one with the attribute and one without--and use an `if.bind` on both, but that seem clunky and un-aurelia like.

Comment: That still outputs the `href` itself though. The corresponding URL is blank, but it's still treated like a hyperlink. I don't want to style the `<a />` as a hyperlink if there is no URL.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think it's supported in Aurelia currently ([issue 1](https://github.com/aurelia/templating/issues/76), [issue 2](https://github.com/aurelia/binding/issues/589))

This,

```
<a href.bind="addLink ? link : ''">Link</a>.
```

will produce

```
<a href>Link</a>
```

if `addLink` is `false`.

It won't remove the `attribute` entirely. If you are using a library which will check the existence of an attribute to manipulate the element, then this won't work. Another option would be to create a custom attribute [like this](https://github.com/aurelia/templating/issues/76#issuecomment-255542154). But that seems like an overhead.